# Otto: Fragment subscriptions not receiving events

Tags: android, otto

I've got a fragment and have registered and unregistered the bus in the fragments `onResume` and `onPause` methods. Using the following `BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);` and `BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);`.

I have a subscription defined like so:

```
@Subscribe public void onLogin(LoggedInEvent event) {
    // Do Something
}
```

I also have another subscription for the same event in the activity the fragment is attached to and that subscription reacts and does it's thing. So my question is why doesn't my fragment receive the event for `LoggedInEvent`?

**Edit:**
I've also registered/unregistered the bus in my activity's `onResume` and `onPause` methods as well.

**Edit 2:**
The bus was instantiated with `ThreadEnforcer.ANY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that the class that was posting the events to the bus, but wasn't running on the main/ui thread which was causing inconstancies with being able to see changes happen in the ui and reacting properly. So now my class is posting on the main thread and I removed the `ThreadEnforcer.ANY` from creating my bus so that now everything for sure is running on the main thread.